# Chaning CSS and content of DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change some of the content of a div as well as its CSS after a button is clicked. I am trying to use jquery to do so but simply having two divs and changing their visibility after the button click. Right now when I click nothing happens and the same div remains visible. I am making a web app mostly using php, html and a MySQL database. I have dbconnect.php which connects to the database where all the content of the div is fetched from. Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: index.php');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: index.php");
}

?>

<?php include ('dbconnect.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>UPM</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        #proj{
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 50px 50px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #projcom{
            display: none;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-color: green;
            font-color: green;
        }

        #notcom{
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 50px 50px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-color: red;
            border-color: red;
        }

        .jumbotron {
            background-color: #f4511e;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 100px 25px;

        }

        .bg-grey{
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .container-fluid{
            padding: 60px 50px;
        }

        .logo {
            font-size: 200px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

            .col-sm-4 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 25px 0;
            }

        }

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #f4511e;
            z-index: 9999;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: #f4511e !important;
            background-color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            color: #fff !important;

        }

    </style>
</head>



<body id="MyProjects" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand">

                <!-- logo not working-->

                <!-- <IMG SRC="images/UPMLogo.jpg" width="230px" height="158px">-->

            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>

                <li><a href="myprojects.php">MY PROJECTS</a></li>

                <li><a href="eval.php">EVALUATIONS</a></li>

                <li><a href="#pricing">MY STATS</a></li>

                <li><a href="hints.php">HINTS & TIPS</a></li>

                <li><a href="home.php?logout='1'">LOG OUT</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>



<div class="jumbotron text-center">

    <h1 id =SiteTitle> Welcome to your MyProjects page! </h1>

    <h3>Here you will be able to enter all of your university projects along with their deliverable's and deadlines. You can mark your projects as successful or unsuccessful depending on whether you met the deadline.
        It is a great way to visually track all of your projects!</h3>

</div>


<div class=""container-fluid">

<p>
To get add a project click on the plus symbol. If a project is completed on time with all the deliverables' mark it with the tick! Otherwise click on the X.
</p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div>
                <form method="post" action="myprojects.php">

                    <div class=""input-group>
                    Project Title :<br>
                    <input type="text" name="projtitle"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    Deliverable 1 :<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    <input type="text" name="del1"><br>
                    Deliverable 2 :<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    <input type="text" name="del2"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    Deliverable 3 :<br>
                    <input type="text" name="del3"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    Final Deadline Date: <br>
                    <input type="date" name="deadline"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""input-group>
                    Choose a Colour: <br>
                    <input type="color" name="colour"><br><br>
                    </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addproj">+</button>
                <p><strong>Click me, click me!</strong></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    <!--Display projects-->
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div id='proj' class='col-sm-4'>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['title'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Deliverables: </p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['del1'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['del2'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['del3'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Deadline date:</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['deadline'] . "</p>";
            $target = strtotime($row['deadline']);
            $today = time();
            $difference = $target - $today;
            $days = (int)($difference / 86400);
            print $days;
            echo "<p>days until deadline</p>";
            echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"combtn\" name=\"combtn\">√</button> <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\" name=\"notcom\">X</button>";
            echo "</div>";

        echo "<div id='projcom' class='col-sm-4'>";
        echo "<p>" . $row['title'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Deadline date:</p>";
        echo "<p>" . $row['deadline'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Project complete and deadline met!</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    ?>


    <script>
        $(".combtn").click(function () {
            $("#proj").css("display", "none");
            $("#projcom").css("display", "block");
        }
        )
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also as you can see the divs are fetched in a loop so every project/row taken from the database is displayed in a new div. I want to make sure when the button is clicked it only changes the visibility of that one div not every project being displayed. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Bootstrap JS integration is an unclosed JS tag => All of your HTML below that is considered JS, until the first closing tag (</script>).

Additionally, many of your classes are out of the quotes. E.g. `class=""some-class`. This way it is considered the element has no class and `some-class` is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
      $(".combtn").click(function () {
          $("#proj").css("display", "none");
          $("#projcom").css("display", "block");
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors which I can see:

1. Add `bootstrap.min.js` after `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` since it's depending on jQuery.
2. You need to use classes for your rows instead of IDs because IDs can't be duplicated in a single HTML page.

After changing ID `proj` and `projcom` to a class, change your JavaScript code like this. Using `$(this).closest(".proj")` you can only get the currently clicked button row that you want to hide.
And then you can get the next row with `$(this).next(".projcom")` to access the next row that you want to show.

```
 $(function(){
    $(".combtn").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".proj").css("display", "none"); 
        $(this).next(".projcom").css("display", "block");
    });
 });
```

Instead of using the `css()` method to show or hide an element, you can use the jQuery built-in methods `show()` to show the element and `hide()` to hide it.

```
$(this).closest(".proj").hide(); 
$(this).next(".projcom").show();
```

Comment: Bootstrap JS is not required for utilising jQuery, but jQuery is required for using Bootstrap JS.

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov Please read point 1 carefully . Where I write jquery depends on bootstrap ?.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood you, probably for you have a few grammatical issues.